# How to use binary variables to satisfy if/then linear constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to solve the constraint $c$ where:
 $$c=\begin{cases} 
      50\sigma & \text{if $\sigma < 0$},\\
      150\sigma & \text{if $\sigma \geq 0$}. 
   \end{cases}
$$

I know I need to use binary variables but do I need to use two -one for each case? If so, how can I turn each variable on/off if sigma is negative? I cannot seem to formulate a constraint that is not satisfied when the binary variable is positive and negative.

Comment: A binary variable normally takes values in $\{0,1\}$. Are you instead using variables that take values in $\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: Welcome to OR StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce one binary variable $x\in\{0,1\}$ and the following linear constraints:
\begin{equation}
-\sigma \le M_1 x\\
-M_2 (1-x) \le c-50 \sigma \le M_3 (1-x)\\
\sigma \le M_4 (1-x)\\
-M_5 x \le c-150 \sigma \le M_6 x
\end{equation}
The various $M_i$ are big-M constants.

The first constraint enforces $\sigma < 0 \implies x=1$.  The second constraint enforces $x=1 \implies c=50\sigma$. The third constraint enforces $\sigma > 0 \implies x=0$.  The fourth constraint enforces $x=0 \implies c=150\sigma$.

**Update**: With @prubin's suggestions, assuming $L \le \sigma \le U$ for some constants $L$ and $U$, the constraints become:
\begin{equation}
L x \le \sigma \le U (1-x)\\
0 \le c-50 \sigma \le 100 U (1-x)\\
0 \le c-150 \sigma \le -100 L x
\end{equation}

Comment: In Rob's answer, $-M_1$ and $M_4$ would be the endpoints of the domain of $\sigma$. So you would need to know a priori that $-M_1 \le \sigma \le M_4$. You can safely use $100M_4$ as the value for $M_3$ and $100M_1$ as the value for $M_6$. $M_2$ and $M_5$ can be set to 0.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, using one variable makes more sense than what I was formulating with two!